# Django : How can I update my views? url problem

Tags: django

Like below code, I made update view but it doesn't work. after I click the , it doesn't work an just

> "GET /moneylogs/update/7/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6243

console log printed. the page remain like just refresh.

How can I update my moneylog?
**views.py**

```
class moneylog_update(UpdateView):
    model = moneylog_models.Moneylog
    form_class = forms.UpdateMoneylogForm
    template_name = "moneylogs/update.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        moneylog = form.save(commit=False)
        moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(
            pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        moneylog.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(reverse("moneybooks:detail", kwargs={'pk': moneybook.pk}))
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = "moneylogs"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/<int:pk>/",
         views.moneylog_create.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("update/<int:pk>/",
         views.moneylog_update.as_view(), name="update"),
    path("<int:moneybook_pk>/delete/<int:moneylog_pk>/",
         views.moneylog_delete, name="delete"),
]
```

**moneylog_form_update.html**

```
  <div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="w-1/4">
                {{form.memo.label}} 
            </div>
            <div class="w-3/4 border-b my-2 py-3">
                {{form.memo}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if form.memo.errors %}
            {% for error in form.memo.errors %}
                <span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span> 
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
<a href="{% url 'moneylogs:update' moneylog.pk %} ">
    <div class="px-2 py-1 rounded bg-red-500 text-white">{{cta}}</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Update view processes the form on a post request, you need HTML form with post request to submit your data.

```html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'moneylogs:update' moneylog.pk %}">
 <div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="w-1/4">
                {{form.memo.label}} 
            </div>
            <div class="w-3/4 border-b my-2 py-3">
                {{form.memo}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if form.memo.errors %}
            {% for error in form.memo.errors %}
                <span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span> 
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="{{cta}}" />
</form>
```

`<a></a>` will hit the server using the `GET` request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! if you don't mind, could you check this out? I edit it like :     <button class="px-2 py-1 rounded bg-red-500 text-white">{{cta}}</button>
    <a href="{% url 'moneylogs:delete' moneybook.pk moneylog.pk %} " >
        <div class="px-2 py-1 rounded bg-red-500 text-white">delete</div>
    </a>
but error occur : Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('', 7)' not found. do you know how can fix it?

Comment: looks like `moneybook.pk` is empty here, need more info regarding that. maybe a new question with some views :)